# Global.asax events are not being raised

Tags: iis, events, deployment, web-applications, global-asax

After deployment on IIS 6 methods declared in Global.asax (for Application Start, etc.) are not executed. The same code on IIS 5 works properly. What can be the reason? Is it the problem with permissions/configuration?

Comment: is the IIS configured to use "webgarden"?

Comment: not a webgarden. by the way we use ASP.NET 2

Comment: a project was converted to a web application when we moved to VS 2008, and the problem seems to be with deployment of code behind global.asax. We'll check it later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed by dropping the file precompiledapp.config from root.

Answer (score 0):

Is the virtual folder in IIS configured as an 'application' ?

Comment: Yes, it was the first thing we've checked.

Comment: Was just making sure, sometimes it's the first thing to forget  :) Glad you found the answer.

Comment: Thanks :) Actually, it wasn't me who found it :)